# How to create a desktop-entry in Gnome

Tags: gnome

I posted this question yesterday on stackexchange but I was told that it should have been posted here.

I have installed ProM 6.8 (a process mining tool, written in Java) and after executing the command ./ProM68.sh & in a terminal, the application starts without problems.

I tried to create both a desktop-entry in Gnome 3 (on Fedora 28) or a menu-item.

This is my desktop-entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Prom
Exec=/home/bengbers/Programs/Prom/ProM68.sh %u
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false  
Categories=Development;Java;
```

After double-clicking this iscon, nothing happens.

I also tried adding an entry in the main-menu but this entry fails also.

How can I create a working desktop entry?

Ben

Comment: Have you placed this file into `~/.local/share/applications` as `something.desktop`?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `ProM68.sh` script, you can see, that it sets the class path relative to the current working directory, not the directory containing the script. So if you are running `./ProM68.sh` your current working directory is the same as the directory containing the script, that's why it works if you run it this way. Desktop files are usually launched with the home directory as current working directory unless you specify a path like `Path=/home/bengbers/Programs/Prom`. (Also you have some trailing spaces after the `false` for the `Terminal` key according to `desktop-file-validate`, but that's probably not causing any issues.)

Comment: After adding a line with the Path, the desktop-entry works.

Thanks